# How would I check if an input from the user is a float?

Tags: c

I want to write an if statement where if the user input is a float then X happens but I don't actually know how to translate this in to code. The code is below so if anyone could help me that would be great.

```
// declare a variable
float i = 0;

// ask for an input
scanf( "%f", &i );

// if the input is a float
if() <--- DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE
{
// print normally
printf();
} 

// in all other cases
else 
{
// print an error message
printf();
}
```

Sorry if this is a really simple question but I'm very new to learning C.

Comment: Read in a string, try to convert to `float`, check what happens.

Comment: In addition to what @DeiDei said, you can check if it's a number, infinity, within a range, etc. as needed. See [this article as an example of some different checks you can perform](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FLP04-C.+Check+floating-point+inputs+for+exceptional+values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the return value of the `scanf` call -- it tells you how many conversions succeeded:

```
if (scanf("%f", &i) == 1) {
    // the input is a float
} else {
    // all other cases -- print an error message
}
```

Comment: But note that a successful conversion does not ensure that the whole input was consumed.  For example, scanning "1.0XYZ" as you describe will successfully scan the value `1.0` into variable `i`, returning 1, and leaving the "XYZ" waiting to be read.

Answer (score 1):

Read it as a string first:

```
char message[100+1];
char *end = NULL;
double result = 0.0;
scanf("%100s", message);
```

Then try a safe conversion to double:

```
result = strtod(message, &end);
if ((end == message) || errno == ERANGE)) {

    // not a floating point value

}
else {
    // is a floating point value - stored in result
}
```

Comment: `result == 0.0` not needed in `(result == 0.0 && end == message)`.    `(result == HUGE_VAL || result == -HUGE_VAL)` is an incorrect test.  Test for `errno`

Comment: This code accepts “9z” as a valid input, because `end == message` accepts any input for which a non-null prefix satisfy the `strtod` syntax. It is not clear OP wants that. To test whether the entire string constituted an acceptable `strtod` value, use `*end == '\0' || *message == '\0'` (the latter is needed to reject the case where the input string is empty).

Answer (score 1):

To test if user input is a `float`

Step 1: Read input as a string using `fgets()` [@DeiDei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361728/how-would-i-check-if-an-input-from-the-user-is-a-float/50362269#comment87739885_50361728).  Best to avoid `scanf()`.

```
char buf[1000];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  puts("End-of-file or rare input error occurred");
  return;
}
```

Could test (not shown) if buffer is such that use input was too large.  IMO, consider that a hostile attack.

Now parse the string;

```
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
float f = strtof(buf, &endptr);
if (buf == endptr) {
  puts("No conversion");
  return;
}

while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr) endptr++;
if (*endptr) {
  puts("trailing junk");
  return;
}

if (errno == ERANGE) {
  puts("Out of `float` range.");  // too big or maybe too small
  // suggest continue on and use the +/- HUGE_VALF or wee number. 
} else if (errno) {
  puts("Implementation additional error.");
  return; 
}

// use `f`
```